# Adding multiple forms and inputs with onclick events using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am currently working on an website project that my friends and I would like to publish in the future. I´m currently building the html and css side of the page and need to implement dynamic events (if that's how its called) in the page for customer input.

I have a very little understanding when it comes to javascript/jquery (I am able to get a general idea of what is happening, yet my syntax comprehension is poop) and have only a basic knowledge of html and css. Now, I am aware that my inquiry is extensive and I would really appreciate any help, or pointers in the right direction!

So far the different blocks of code that I have found and tried by googling have worked for me, but only in executing individual functions (e.g.: the toggle function works but the create.element function doesn't).

This is my current html code that I am trying to modify with Javascript:

```
<div class="bttiendas">

<button class="btndag">Agregar</button>
<button class="btndgu">Guardar</button>

</div>

<div class="rdatos">

<form class="thf">
<input class="morehf" type="button" value="+/-" />
<input class="chf" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum" readonly  />
<input class="chf" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum" readonly  />
<input class="chf" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum" readonly  />
<input class="edithf" type="button" value="Edit" />
<input class="erasehf" type="reset" value="Erase" />
</form>

<form class="trf">
<input class="crf" type="text" placeholder="POS" readonly />
<input class="crf" type="text" disabled />
<input class="crf" type="text" disabled />
<input class="crf" type="text" disabled />
</form>

</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish with Javascript is as follows:

-To be able to create with javascript both `.thf` and `.trf` forms dynamically along with every other input/button that is inside each form with clicking the `.btndag` button (this is an `onclick` event followed by `create.element` if I'm not mistaken).

-For the `.morehf <input button>` have a hide/show toggle function for `.trf` and anything else inside that form.

-Toggle disabled in the `.crf` input text boxes with the `.edithf <input button>`.

-To be able to erase/remove both `.thf` and `.trf` forms (their input textboxes AND the buttons `.morehf .edithf .erasehf`) with the `.erasehf <input button>`.

-And to be able to save/submit (I am not sure which is the correct term here) any added and completely filled out forms fields (for when we want to send the changes to our database).

Again I would greatly appreciate any help you could give me, and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: By "add" `tht` and `trf` are you referring to show and hiding it or creating the element? I am not clear on what you want

Comment: Sorry I meant to create! Let me clarify that.

Comment: Sorry it is not clear. What do you mean by create?

Comment: Is this a start? https://jsfiddle.net/mx41hkjt/1  ...When you click Agregar the form is appended

Comment: Yes it indeed it is something that I was struggling with! Thank you so much!

Comment: How are you planning on submitting the data? PHP?

Comment: We plan on using ASP.NET for submitting the data

Comment: Okay that works. https://jsfiddle.net/mx41hkjt/2/ I have now added the hide and show toggle. Let me know if thats correct. Btw, I am writing everything in pure JavaScript, let me know if you would like it in jQuery

Comment: Works perfectly! I'm taking note on the javascript code to make sure I learn.

Comment: What did you want to do with the readonly field? https://jsfiddle.net/mx41hkjt/3/

Comment: I will be removing that readonly attribute from the fields so that the users can input their respective information later on.

Comment: Here is a full version of the form..it is a bit more complex than the posted answer but I use a few different vanilla JavaScript techniques that jQuery hides from you. I do not recommend using jQuery until you understand it without: https://jsfiddle.net/mx41hkjt/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can import jquery into your solution.

For step 1: you do not make sense. Do you mean you want to load data into your form from somewhere to edit data or something? how is this dynamic? It looks like static forms on a page.

For step 2:

```
   <input class="morehf" onclick="toggleTrf()" type="button" value="+/-" />

  <script>
        function toggleTrf() {
           $(".trf").toggle()
           }
  </script>
```

step 3:

```
    <input class="edithf" onclick="disableInputs()" type="button" value="Edit" />     

   <script>
       function disableInputs() {

          if($(".crf").is(":disabled");){

          //jquery 1.6+
          $(".crf").prop('disabled', false);
          //jquery 1.5 -
          $(".crf").removeAttr('disabled');
          }
          else {
          //jquery 1.6+
          $(".crf").prop('disabled', true);
          //jquery 1.5 -
          $(".crf").attr('disabled','disabled');
          }
          }
 </script>
```

step 4:  it is not clear what you mean by erase the form but you can clear the text in the inputs

```
    <input class="erasehf" thpe="reset" onclick="clearInputs()" value="Erase" />

  <script>
       function clearInputs() {
             $("input").val("")
          }
  </script>
```

step 5:

```
    <form action="some/path">
       <input name="someName" type="text" text="random field" value="1" />
       <button type="submit">submit</button>
     </form>
```

That submit button will submit the form to whatever path you specify in your form action. As for saving to the database etc it is impossible to guess what technology you will use to do that.sorry about code formattin im typing on a phone.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear on my first step. The page will load user information (retrieved from the database) into those forms and display it, apart from that they will also have the option of adding blank forms so that they can input new information and save it. I am new to this environment and do have trouble using the correct jargon, still thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have included everything the OP wanted. The non-jQuery approach (ES6). [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx41hkjt/7/)

First lets add a few helper variables:

```
let formSets = 0;
let createForm = function(id) {
    return `<form data-id='${id}' class="thf">
        <input class="morehf" type="button" value="+/-" />
        <input class="chf" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum" readonly  />
        <input class="chf" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum" readonly  />
        <input class="chf" type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum" readonly  />
        <input class="edithf" type="button" value="Edit" />
        <input class="erasehf" type="reset" value="Erase" />
        </form>

        <form data-id='${id}' class="trf">
            <input class="crf" type="text" placeholder="POS" readonly />
            <input class="crf" type="text" disabled />
            <input class="crf" type="text" disabled />
            <input class="crf" type="text" disabled />
        </form>`;
};
```

Add the onclick event for the "add" function. We have to reassign the click events to the dynamically added elements or we could have done event delegation like I did for the remove button:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btndag')[0].onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML += createForm(++formSets);

    for (let ii = 0; ii < formSets; ii++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("morehf")[ii].onclick = () => {
            document.getElementsByClassName("trf")[ii].classList.toggle('hide');
        }

        document.getElementsByClassName("edithf")[ii].onclick = () => {
            let form = document.getElementsByClassName("trf")[ii].children;
            for (let i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
                let input = form[i];

                if (input.disabled == true) {
                    input.disabled = false;
                } else {
                    input.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Add the remove button a little differently using event delegation which allows us to target another element based on the parents target:

```
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function(e) {
    let t = e.target;

    if (t.className == 'erasehf') {
        let me = t.parentNode;
        let sib = me.nextElementSibling;

        me.parentNode.removeChild(me);
        sib.parentNode.removeChild(sib);
    }
}
```

Finally, submit the data. This part is a little more vague simply because I am not exactly sure how you want the data formatted. But here is how you would submit the form using AJAX:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btndgu')[0].onclick = function() {
    Request("/linkto/save.asp").post({
        //datahere
    }).then(function () {
        //on success
    }, function () {
        //on failure
    });
}
```

Note that this uses a helper AJAX function that I made:

```
let Request = function(url, opt) {
    // start loader
    var AJAX = function(type, url, data, success, failure, cache) {
        var InitRequest = new Promise(function(accept, reject) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // initiate new XMLHttpRequest
            var done = false;
            var compile = function(data) { //turn the data object into a usable source for the send function
                var send = [];
                for (var item in data) { // compile all data in "item=data" strings
                    send.push(item + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[item]));
                }
                send = send.join("&"); // combine data to form "item1=data1&item2=dat2&item3=data3"
                return send;
            };

            // if we choose not send any data, then the data variable will take the place of the success variable
            // because of this, we have to also shift the failure function
            if (typeof data === "function") {
                success = data || accept;
                failure = success || reject;
                data = "";
            } else {
                success = success || accept;
                failure = failure || reject;
                data = compile(data);
            }

            if (type.toUpperCase() == 'POST') {
                request.open(type.toUpperCase(), url, true);

                // this header allows POST requests to work
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            } else if (type.toUpperCase() == 'GET') {
                // for GET requests, we need to put all data in the url 
                // we would end up with test.php?item1=data1&item2=dat2&item3=data3
                request.open(type.toUpperCase(), url + "?" + data, true);
            } else {
                console.error('Incorrect request type submitted: "' + type + '" is not supported.');
                return false;
            }

            // in order for laravel to properly send ajax requests
            request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
            request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (!done) {
                    if (request.readyState === 4) { // when the readyState == 4, we have completed the request
                        if (request.status === 200 || request.status === 0 /*for ff bug*/ ) {
                            success(request.responseText, request);
                        } else { //if failed
                            try {
                                request.responseJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                            } catch (e) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            failure(request);
                        }
                        // hide the loader because the request has finished
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
            };

            // send off the request
            request.send(data);
        });
        return InitRequest;
    };

    // The "opt" variable also goes into place as the 
    // Cache reset
    if (opt && typeof opt !== "string" && typeof opt !== "boolean") {
        var DEFAULTS = {
            type: "GET",
            data: {},
            cache: false,
            success: function() {},
            failure: function() {}
        };
        var o = $.extend(DEFAULTS, opt);

        return AJAX(o.type, url, o.data, o.success, o.failure, o.cache);
    } else {

        return {
            post: function(data, success, failure, cache) {
                return AJAX("POST", url, data, success, failure, cache);
            },
            get: function(data, success, failure, cache) {
                return AJAX("GET", url, data, success, failure, cache);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A little more information about sending data via AJAX**

Data in your case should correspond with the ids:

```
{
     0: {
         trf: {
             input1: "..",
             input2: "..",
             input3: ".."
         } 
     },
     1: {
         trf: {
             input1: "..",
             input2: "..",
             input3: ".."
         } 
     }
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work, thank you very much for the help!